# Image Mapping On android

Tags: android, image, layout

**Hi I am trying to make Hotspot on image but the problem is when screen size change hotspot location is also got change**

> I have done following things as of now
>
> Bellow is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="myapp.imagemappingdemo.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="7000pt"
    android:layout_height="5000pt">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bolt_int"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/upperView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

> I am using following code to plot the image.

```
    screenWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    ImageView btn = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bp = new    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    bp.leftMargin = (int) (774.6667 );
    bp.topMargin = (int) (413.25);
    btn.setLayoutParams(bp);
    btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    upperview.addView(btn, bp);
```

**I am trying to figure out how I am going to calculate exactly position on different screen by using same (X,Y) coordinate can any one help me in doing so what is the relation between Screen height and width and  (X , y)  coordinate irrespective of screen size**

Comment: You should learn about responsive layouts because in this why you are not getting the hotspot at exact location is because parent size changes when you switch between mobiles.

Comment: exactly where you want that hotspot ? in the middle of imageview??

Comment: no it could be at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your following code is working for a particular screen,

```
bp.leftMargin = (int) (774.6667 );
bp.topMargin = (int) (413.25);
```

then just change the values as per screen height and width, let say it's working fine for 800 x 480 -

```
int standardWidth = 480;
int standardHeight = 800;
bp.leftMargin = ((int) (774.6667 ) * dm.widthPixel)/standardWidth;
bp.topMargin = ((int) (413.25) * dm.heightPixel)/standardHeight;
```

Now the leftMargin and topMargin will be updated according to screen size.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: what do you mean by standard width and standard height

Comment: Standard means, for the screen 774.6667 , 413.25 are working fine. Let suppose it's working fine for 1280x800. then 1280 is standard height and 800 is standard width.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make Imageview Wrap content and then in java first get the position of ImageView and than add the margin to it and set it to hotspot view

Answer (score 0):

Change X,Y of Hotspot as % position on the image - e.g. image has 100px width, and access point X is 10, so it has X=0.1.
Next, get image matrix of image view to float array:

```
float[] values = new float[9];
btn.getImageMatrix().getValues(values)
```

on the 2nd index you have left image position, and on the 5th - top image position. Then you can get correct Hotspot position:

```
float hotspotX = btn.getWidth()*X + values[2];
float hotspotY = btn.getHeight()*Y + values[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code gives the hieght and width of the screen,

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
x = size.x; y = size.y;
```

(x/2,y/2) this gives the center position in the screen.

U can set the leftmargin and rightmargin in terms of y like:

```
bp.leftMargin = 10*y/100;
bp.rightMargin = 10*y/100;
```

this sets your image 10% away from left and right margin.

Hope this helps! U can make changes according to your requirements.